# Highlighting elements the cursor is on using mouseenter/mouse leave is very slow

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use the cursor to highlight elements the cursor lands on, and when the cursor leaves it restores it to its original color. The problem is that it does not respond to every element the cursor lands on, and sometimes the highlighting remains even if the cursor has left.

JS

```
$('body').mouseenter(function(evt){
    if(popusIsOpen) {
        $(evt.target).toggleClass('mouseOn', true);
    }
});

$('body').mouseleave(function(evt){
    if(popusIsOpen) {
        $(evt.target).toggleClass('mouseOn', false);
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.function == 'popup') {
            popusIsOpen = true;
        }

    });
```

CSS

```
.mouseOn {
    background-color: #99ccff
}
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do it. Look into the `:hover` css pseudo class - it's designed exactly for this. ;)

Comment: Yeah the reason I'm doing it this way is because this is a content script in a chrome extension. I'm technically "hijacking" whatever website the user is on. I'll look into this and see if I can append and strip out the `:hover` css. Thanks!

Comment: you can add css rules dynamically, and from within content scripts. So long as you know what you want to target, just create and append a rule to do it. I've done it and there are plugins that allow you to highlight the element under the cursor. (Oh, and you're welcome)